# How to create a start menu screen with Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, screen, panel, frame

This creates a jframe with 3 rows and 4 columns. Im trying to achieve a memory game where it matches the letters. I want to make it so that when the program runs it will create a exit button and a start button, which will go onto the game. I'm fairly new to Jpanel and Jframe. Another question how would you change the size of the font?

```
   import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;


public class matchinggame implements ActionListener 
{
    JPanel jp = new JPanel(); //lets us use the variables jp
    JFrame jf = new JFrame(); //lets us use the variables jf

    String[] matchList = { "dank", "dank", "memes", "memes", "360", "360", "headshot", "headshot", "doge", "doge",
            "mlg", "mlg",};  
    String[] shuffledList;

    JButton[][] buttons;

    int i = 0;
    int cardOne;
    int secIndex;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //creates app and Gui

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() //launches a thread that will run a class later
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                matchinggame app = new matchinggame();
                app.makeGUI();
            }
        });

    }

    public void dealCards(JPanel panel) 
    {
        buttons = new JButton[3][4]; // array of buttons used to represent cards
        shuffleCards();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 * 4; i++)  // creates 3 rows with 4 columns     
        {                       
            if (i % 4 == 0)
                buttons[i / 4] = new JButton[4];
            buttons[i / 4][i % 4] = new JButton("choose me"); // shows cards faced down
            buttons[i / 4][i % 4].addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(buttons[i / 4][i % 4]);
        }
    }

    public void shuffleCards() 
    {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(matchList);
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        shuffledList = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }

    public void updateMatchList(String a, String b, boolean add) 
    {
        String[] courseList;
        int oldLen = matchList.length;

        if (add) // add the new item to the list
        { 
            courseList = new String[oldLen + 2];
            courseList[0] = new String(a); // new first course
            courseList[1] = new String(b); // new first course num
            for (int item = 2; item <= oldLen; item += 2) 
            {
                courseList[item] = matchList[item - 2];
                courseList[item + 1] = matchList[item - 1];
            }
            matchList = courseList;// delete matching item
        } 
            else 
        { 
            courseList = new String[oldLen - 2];
            int matchItem = 0;
            for (int item = 0; item <= oldLen; item += 2) {
                if (a != matchList[item]) { // no match so OK to copy over
                    courseList[item] = matchList[matchItem];
                    courseList[item + 1] = matchList[matchItem + 1];
                    matchItem += 2;
                }
            }
            matchList = courseList;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Creates the JFrame and its components.
     */
    public void makeGUI() 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("matchinggame"); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jp = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 4));
        jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        dealCards(jp);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Display the window.
        frame.setSize(500, 500);   //creates frame
        frame.setVisible(true);    //shows frame


        jp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.ORANGE,16));



    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
  {
        int r, c;

        if (i < 2) // find the card clicked on and flip it over
        { 

            for (r = 0; r < 3; r++) 
            {
                for (c = 0; c < 4; c++) 
                {
                    // if the card is not face down (showing "choose me") don't
                    // flip it
                    if ((e.getSource() == buttons[r][c])
                            && buttons[r][c].getText().equals("choose me")) 
                    {
                        // flip the card face-up to show text from matchList
                        buttons[r][c].setText(shuffledList[(r * 4 + c)]);
                        i++; // increment number of cards flipped
                        if (i == 1)
                            cardOne = (r * 4 + c); // save which pattern was
                                                    // shown first
                        else
                            secIndex = (r * 4 + c); // save the pattern
                                                    // shown second
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else { // 2 cards already flipped, put all cards face down

            for (r = 0; r < 3; r++) 
            {
                for (c = 0; c < 4; c++) 
                {
                    // first and second cards flipped
                    if (shuffledList[cardOne].equals(shuffledList[secIndex])) 
                    {
                        if (!buttons[r][c].getText().equals("choose me")) //if cards dont match set this card
                            {
                        buttons[r][c].setText("dankified"); //when matched changes card
                        buttons[r][c].setBackground(Color.GREEN);  //when matched changes color of card
                        buttons[r][c].setEnabled(false);    //matched cards will not be able to clicked 
                            }

                    } else if ((!buttons[r][c].getText().equals("dankified"))
                            && (!buttons[r][c].getText().equals("choose me"))) 
                    {
                        // if 2 face up cards didn't match, flip face down again
                        buttons[r][c].setText("choose me");
                    }
                }
                i = 0; // new turn, no cards flipped face up
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*how would you change the size of the font?*" [Search](https://www.google.co.il/search?client=opera&q=java+how+to+change+swing+font&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=java+swing+how+to+change+font).

Comment: You have to be more precise about what you want. When you launch the program for the first time, you want an OK and Cancel options to appear somewhere (where?)?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a confirmation dialog that will be checked before creating the Frame

```
public void makeGUI() {

javax.swing.JOptionPane jOptionPane = new JOptionPane();
if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "start playing ?", "card memory game", 2)==0) {
JFrame frame = new JFrame("matchinggame");  

//rest of your code  ..

}
```

To change the font of your buttons, here's some piece of code to add to your dealCards method (after creating the button)

```
buttons[i / 4][i % 4].setFont(new Font("customFont", FontConstants.ALIGN_CENTER, 24));
```